# Transfer installed application/program via pendrive

Tags: usb, transfer

I have about 25 to 30 computer on which its required to install several applications/programs (like dosbox, mysql, netbeans etc). My Problem is that i have internet connection on only one pc. Is there any way i can download the program on only one pc and saperately install it one-by-one on other pc's via pendrive or dvd's?

Comment: There is no way to get those systems connected?  Internet gateway   (your system is used to let the others connect to the net) might be a possible method. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse.

When you install sofware it downloads .deb files (debiain installer files). You can put those on a pendrive and install them manually. You will yourself have to download all the dependencies though.

Example: dosbox

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/dosbox click the i386 or amd
- and here is a download mirror: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/i386/dosbox/download

The dependencies will take some time to figure out. Most of them might already be installed on those systems so it will be trial and error on the 1st system you install this on.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `remastered DVD` is perhaps the best option for you. Have a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd), which gives extensively explains how to do this.